# Можете расшифровать шифр?

Tags: шифрование

Можете ли вы расшифровать это:

```
ТАЛИЦ ДЬЫЛР ЫНИЦД УЗАЖЧ ВЙЖЙН ЙАЙКЖ АТЧАВ ЫОИЦЭ ИЙЮОЯ ЪФГДК АЭОТА ДМНЛО ИЙДНЦ ВЫТАЗ ВЫЖАН ЫАУЧЭ БГЖЧА ТАЖЙЭ АТЧАГ ЕЫЕЬО ЯНЙНЙ МЕОАУ ЧМЙЗИ ЙДВЫЙ ЕИЙЗМ ЭАНГВ ИЙДКЙ ЯЙЕЙИ ИГЕГЪ ЛЕГЬА ВЗЪНА БИЦГБ ЫЛЕГК ЙМЖАЯ ИГАЯИ ГКЙЖА НЫДКЙ ЮОЯГГ ЭВЫМЙ РУАДН ЫНЫЛЕ АИЫКЙ ЯОУАТ ЕАЕЛЫ МИЙДО МИГИА ЯЫИЙН АЬАВИ ЫНЧТА ЖЙЭАТ АМЕЙД ЯОЗЦТ НЙЯЫЭ ИЙЙКО МНАЖГ КЙЖЪТ НЙОБМ ЕЙЛЙЭ ЬОЛЧЪ ИМЯОА НЭАНА ЛОЮЛЩ ЗЦДВЙ ЖЙНЙЮ ЙМОРЙ ЮЙУЗА ЖЪ
```

похоже на шифр цезаря

Comment: Если зашифровано одноразовым блокнотом, то нет.

Comment: Если творчески подойти к подбору ключа, то это можно расшифровать абсолютно во что угодно, в том числе в что-нибудь экстремистское. Без дополнительной информации об этом шифровании пытаться расшифровывать нет практического смысла.

Comment: это задание для 2-го курса по дисциплине "Информационная безопасность и защита информации" не думаю что должно быть сложно или что то экстремистское

Comment: Значит в этой дисциплине должна быть какая-то дополнительная информация о применяемых в заданиях алгоритмах шифрования.

Comment: Тогда сначала пробуйте частоту букв, а дальше как в старые древние времена, по частоте - угадалка.

Comment: @AlexGlebe если длина ключа больше одного символа, то частота будет неадекватно скакать и придётся применять более сложную модель, а если длина ключа стремится к длине сообщения, то считать по частоте вообще бессмысленно. Кроме того, при желании можно подобрать такой ключ, что по анализу частоты оно расшифруется в безобидных котиков специально для недохакеров, а настоящий ключ расшифрует в что-нибудь про Путина (впрочем, передача такого подобранного ключа становится нетривиальной задачей)

Comment: @andreymal Это только начало, вдруг простой алгоритм. С чего нужно начинать. Дальше нужно перебирать все известные алгоритмы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Итого, 5 минут гугления:
Шифр Цезаря.

Смещение 5.

```
Черный бархатный шмель, золотое оплечье,
Заунывно гудящий певучей струной,
Ты зачем залетаешь в жилье человечье
И как будто тоскуешь со мной?

За окном свет и зной, подоконники ярки,
Безмятежны и жарки последние дни,
Полетай, погуди — и в засохшей татарке,
На подушечке красной, усни.

Не дано тебе знать человеческой думы,
Что давно опустели поля,
Что уж скоро в бурьян сдует ветер угрюмый
Золотого сухого шмеля!
```

Используется русский алфавит без "ё"

Comment: Предположу, что «какой-то буквой» является Ё

Comment: @andreymal что с Ё что без текст не читаем, мне кажется что ответ другой

Comment: Ё не для текста, а для словаря. А насчет читаемости... Посмотрите внимательно: "ЧЕРНЫЙ БАРХАТНЫЙ ШМЕЛЬ ЗОЛОТОЕ ОПЛЕЧЬЕ ЗАУНЫВНО ГУДЯЩИЙ". @igo

Comment: @Leshll да вы правы, пробелы нужно поправить

Answer (score 0):

Формула шифрования :

```
  Шифр X секретные данные => O ( зашифрованное сообщение )
```

создаёт линии от вариантов секретных данных в варианты множества зашифрованных сообщений.

Если известно только `зашифрованное сообщение` то у любых секретных данных будет существовать подходящий шифр. Вы не предоставили ничего, чтобы сузить варианты.

Comment: это задание для 2-го курса по дисциплине "Информационная безопасность и защита информации" не думаю что должно быть сложно - что то типо цезаря или тому подобное. никаких секретных ключей, скорее всего, не нужно

Comment: Не "что-то типо", а точно шифр Цезаря - https://studfile.net/preview/5856679/

Comment: Тогда расшифрованный ответ : `ТАЛИЦ ДЬЫЛР .. ЖЪ` . Подойдёт?

Answer (score 0):

Смещение 5 + поправить пробелы

```
Черный бархатный шмель, золотое оплечье,
Заунывно гудящий певучей струной,
Ты зачем залетаешь в жилье человечье
И как будто тоскуешь со мной?

За окном свет и зной, подоконники ярки,
Безмятежны и жарки последние дни,
Полетай, погуди — и в засохшей татарке,
На подушечке красной, усни.

Не дано тебе знать человеческой думы,
Что давно опустели поля,
Что уж скоро в бурьян сдует ветер угрюмый
Золотого сухого шмеля!
```